# Cucumber-Maven Set up with Eclipse, Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber

I am totally new in Java , and trying to install Cucumber. 
I have downloaded JDK and JRE and their versions are:  jdk-12.0.1  && jre1.8.0_211  and set the environment variables.

I have also downloaded Eclipse

I am following the tutorial https://www.toolsqa.com/cucumber-video-tutorials/

I have downloaded all jar files here, C:\JavaJars\Cucumber
then I have referenced them in my pom.xml file (C:\JavaProjects\CucumberMaven)

Here is a snippet of dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ToolsQA</groupId>
  <artifactId>CucumberMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>CucumberMaven</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.5</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.5</version>
     <type>pom</type>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.13-beta-3</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
     <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.5</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
     <version>4.6.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
     <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
     <version>2.12.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
     <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.13-beta-3</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

in command prompt -->

```
mvn clean install 

I get the error --> 

[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
```

I am not sure how to fix it

Comment: `SHIFT` + `CTRL` + `ALT` + `S`, then choose your JDK 8 as the project JDK.  IntelliJ is defaulting to its built in JDK 5, which you don't want to use.

Answer (score 3):

[maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) by default will compile your project using Java 1.5 which is where m2e gets its information.

Your effective `pom.xml` will implicitly use the default settings in the maven-compiler-plugin `pom.xml.`
That's why you have to explicitly declare the maven-compiler-plugin in your project with something other than 1.5. 
Add this to your `pom.xml`

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Default java version was 1.5, to change the default version added this plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```